# How to make Hazelcast nodes installed in docker on different aws instances interact with each other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cloud, hazelcast

I have three aws machines on which I have setup three docker containers having hazelcast-3.5.4 installed on them(ubuntu).With aws configuration set as what I do normally with Hazelcast(without docker).The nodes are not discovering each other. How to make them interact or discover each other?

Hazelcast.xml file looks like this:

```
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
            <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="false">
            <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
            <member-list>
                <member>127.0.0.1</member>
            </member-list>
        </tcp-ip>
        <aws enabled="true">
            <access-key>Some_key</access-key>
            <secret-key>Secret_key</secret-key>
            <!--optional, default is us-east-1 -->
            <region>us-east-1</region>
            <!--optional, default is ec2.amazonaws.com. If set, region shouldn't be set as it will override this property -->
            <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
            <!-- optional, only instances belonging to this group will be discovered, default will try all running instances -->
            <!--security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name-->
            <tag-key>type</tag-key>
            <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
        </aws>
    </join>

 <public-address>private-ip-of-aws-node</public-address>
<properties>
  <property name="hazelcast.local.localAddress">private-ip-of-aws-node</property>
</properties>
```

Also I have added two more entries as suggested in a similar post somewhere which doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Following is my hazelcast.xml configuration

Comment: I am able to ping node 2 from docker container in node 1 and vice versa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to run your hazelcast docker image with `--net=host` option. I tested with docker image published by hazelcast (https://hub.docker.com/r/hazelcast/hazelcast/) with version 3.5.4 with two instances on aws ec2. My Docker version is `Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5`
 and ami I used on ec2 is `Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type - ami-fce3c696` and here is my `hazelcast.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.5.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <!--
            Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
            0 or * means use system provided port.
            -->
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
                <member-list>
                    <member>127.0.0.1</member>
                </member-list>
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled="true">
                <access-key>your-acces-key</access-key>
                <secret-key>your-secret-key</secret-key>
            </aws>
        </join>
        <public-address>private-ip-address-of-ec2-instance</public-address>
    </network>
    <properties>
       <property name="hazelcast.local.localAddress">private-ip-address-of-ec2-instance</property>
   </properties>
</hazelcast>
```

This is my docker command for running hazelcast image with custom config file :
`docker run --net=host -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dhazelcast.config=/configFolder/hazelcast.xml" -v ~/configFolder:/configFolder -ti hazelcast/hazelcast`

If `--net=host` option does not work, make sure that in your security group config ports used by hazelcast are open as inbound ports. Also you can enable debugging to see more details about nodes discovered by ec2 discovery.

Please see `Debugging` section under hazelcast ec2 discovery section : http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-members-within-ec2-cloud

Comment: Thanks Ibrahim! I tried running the container as you said but I am still not able to make the hazelcast containers interact with each other.ALL TCP ports are open in AWS security group.

Comment: May I know which docker version were you using?

Comment: I am doing every thing as you have explained.Even used your hazelcast.xml file.I am using the same version of docker and all Inbound and Outbound connections have all TCP open.Still I am not able to make them interact.

Comment: What is the ip you see in hazelcast logs. Do you see private ips of your ec2 instances like this ```Members [2] {
 Member [172.31.15.17]:5701 this
 Member [172.31.2.238]:5701
}```.  Also can you enable debugging, when you enable debugging, you should see ip addresses of found ec2 instances starting with log entry `Found the following EC2 instances:`.

Comment: Issue solved...I did not enable UFW in the the two nodes.Now after
sudo ufw enable
it's working..Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: Good news that it is working, I did not expect ufw can cause such problems, I also learned sth today.